# What does snake in the hands of apasmAra signify?

Tags: shiva, symbolism

In Shiva's Nataraj form, there's a demon crushed by Shiva called apasmAra which holds a snake if one looks closely. What does this snake signify according to scriptures?

Comment: ApasmAra signifies ignorance, which Shiva always subdues but doesn't kill (to maintain the cosmic balance viz. *there cannot be light without darkness*). Literally, ApasmAra is the Epilepsy disease. I never heard any symbolic interpretation of the Snake (or sometimes black stick) ApasmAra holds. Maybe the snake represents poison of ignorance which constantly leads to rebirths, death and mortality. And only by subduing the ignorance can one reach Moksha. But, this interpretation needs scriptural verification! :))

Comment: @Vivikta yes I think the same but my friend says, the snake represents kundalini which is hindered by ignorance.